# resetting colaboratory to factory settings

Tags: google-colaboratory

I stupidly (?) pip-installed tensorflow-gpu, and now `import tensorflow as tf` fails with an error (it can't find some shared libraries). Is there a way to reset the environment to "factory settings"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To drop your current backend and start fresh with a new one, select the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do that from a code cell?

Comment: Where is this option? I only see Interrupt execution, restart runtime, restart and execute all cells, reset settings. No factory reset, can't get T4 :(