# How can restart googlecolab runtime with everything clear?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I installed many libs and many settings on colab and now I want to clear all settings, files, libs, and everything on my colab accounts!
Is it possibl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resetting colaboratory to factory settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961289/resetting-colaboratory-to-factory-settings)

Answer (score 11):

To drop your current backend and start fresh with a new one, select the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.
[image]

Comment: strange does not work for me? I have to go and clear the output of each cell manually

Comment: @AEDWIP resetting runtimes refers to the environment the notebook is running in. That is the files, data you have downloaded, packages you have installed with !pip, etc. To clear all output from your notebook, goto 'edit -> clear all output'.

Comment: This is equivalent to resetting the virtual machine colab is running in. So also equivalent to the 12 hours expiring, and resetting the 12 hours countdown to a "fresh" 12 hours. Also note that "restart runtime" is different as it just restarts the python kernel, clearing all variables, but doens't affect the VM.

Comment: what is the difference between  "Factory reset runtime"  and Reset all runtimes..?

Answer (score 11):

In latest Google Colab version, we should select "Factory reset runtime" from "Runtime" drop down menu to reset all runtimes and delete the files.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from 2023

`Runtime` > `Disconnect and delete runtime`