# How to concatenate 1d array from OpenCV function with flatten vector in CNN

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to increase the accuracy of CNN (convolutional neural network) by computing some dynamic values such as Hu moments of the images USING ***OpenCV*** function during the training phase and then feed them to the fully connected layer with the flatten vector as shown in the image of my model:

[My model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imwof.png)

I want to compute Hu moments for each image USING ***OPENCV*** in the dataset then after the flatten operation, I want to concatenate the values of the Hu moments with the fatten vector and feed it to the fully connected layer.

This is the model I'm using (Tensorflow Keras):

```
@tf.function
def calc_hu(imagex):
  imagex=tf.image.convert_image_dtype(imagex, dtype=tf.uint8)    
  moments = cv2.UMat(cv2.moments(imagex))    
  huMoments = cv2.UMat(cv2.HuMoments(moments))
  for i in range(0, 7):
    huMoments[i] = abs(-1 * math.copysign(1.0, huMoments[i]) * math.log10(abs(huMoments[i])))
  huMoments=huMoments.astype(np.uint8) 
  return huMoments

class HuLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):          
      return calc_hu(inputs)



layer1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')(inpx) 
layer2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer1) 
layer3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer2) 
layer4 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer3)
layer5 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer4)
layer6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer5) 
layer7 = Dropout(0.5)(layer6) 
layer8 = Flatten()(layer7) 

layer8_ =tf.keras.layers.concatenate([layer8,  HuLayer()(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]).shape))(inpx)])
layer9 = Dense(250, activation='sigmoid')(layer8_) 
layer10 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(layer9) 

model = Model([inpx], layer10) 



model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), 
              loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
              metrics=['accuracy']) 





model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=500) 
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

But I'm still having this error

```
TypeError: in converted code:

<ipython-input-1-dd21806afc67>:155 call  *
    return calc_hu(inputs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py:449 __call__
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
<ipython-input-1-dd21806afc67>:143 calc_hu  *
    moments = cv2.UMat(cv2.moments(imagex))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py:396 converted_call
    return py_builtins.overload_of(f)(*args)

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

HuLayer is expected to get an image of size 28X28 and return Hu moments which are ***seven*** values so they can be concatenated with the flatten vector

The dataset I'm using is MNIST handwritten digits.

Answer (score 0):

`imagex` should be a NumPy array.

```
imagex = imagex.numpy()
moments = cv2.UMat(cv2.moments(imagex))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I got this error  `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: Which TF version are you using?

Comment: TF version 1.15.0

Comment: Did you enable eager mode? `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()`

Comment: no I haven't how can I do that on google colaboratory

Comment: `tf.enable_eager_execution()`

Comment: Where exactly should I write it

Comment: After `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: I got this error `ValueError: tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup.`

Comment: Restart Colab runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361934/how-can-restart-googlecolab-runtime-with-everything-clear

Comment: I restarted the runtime now I have this error `RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.`